# Power return and grounding - Is there a right way?

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, grounding, isolation, ground-loop

I'm currently designing a multi-PCB system with many power rails and return paths, but I'm not sure if keeping power rails isolated and only linked together on the PCBs is better from a noise/ground loop perspective as compared to commoning up the PSUs on the backplane where the power supplies come in. Some scribbles attached.

I've been trying to find a right answer, and come to the conclusion there isn't really one and it just "depends".

Any advice?

[image]

Comment: It totally depends on many more details about what each PCB connects to externally. Total isolation may be required in some circumstances along with differential digital and analogue communication lines.

Comment: I would tend towards the right side image (also assuming ground planes on the cards).  Then if there was an issue with one of the signals or analog noise, deal with it as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the current return path. An isolated supply with its own current return path does not create common mode noise on the ground. A common ground will create common mode noise.

The problem is the resistance in the ground from the return current, and the second problem is switching loads.

Lets say I have 1A going through 50mΩ of connectors on a bus and wiring, that would create a common mode voltage if 50mV. That probably won't be a problem for most applications, and it's a constant offset.

Also consider if that 1A goes to 2A at X Hz. You'll then go from 50mV to 100mV and everything on the board will see 50mV of common mode noise. If its switching that will not be good for most applications.

The last thing to consider is the voltage regulators on the board, lets say you have a 5V LDO, it will regulate the voltage to 5V above it's local ground. So if it's ground goes up 50mV, so does it's output. Which is fine for analog electronics for the most part, unless you are doing really low level stuff, then they will see the switching noise.

At the end of the day, the trick is to lower the common mode noise, there are innumerable ways to do this. You can do separate grounds, you can do a common ground but route the common mode return switching current away from the sensitive sections. You can isolate the analog sections (and the digital adcs) so there is no currents or common mode voltages through those sections.
You can isolate the whole board. You can lower the connector resistance until there is very very little common mode voltage on the ground.

The trick is to keep track of the return currents and do a little homework.

Answer (score 1):

There are many better reference books on EMC initiated for minimizing interference between Agnd =Analog and Dgnd=digital, but don't neglect  the signals  and power that use this as 0.V reference point.

[I recommend you read what I used 50 yrs ago.](https://archive.org/details/noisereductionte0000otth) That's a great start.

Also...
https://www.amazon.ca/Henry-W-Ott/e/B001IOFFSE/ref=aufs_dp_fta_dsk

EMC has not changed in 50 yrs in theory, but practice may differ and Henry knew how to explain it better than I.

Remember than EMC is caused by both conducted and radiated interference which are coupled by a network transfer function (that may be complex) with RLC conductive and parasitic (radiated) impedances.

**Your question cannot be completely answered in a 2D symbolic diagram as geometry for the previous reasons. But in general. A shared point should be as close as possible to the sensitive target after which there is no crosstalk nor shared conductors.**

For example, Analog differential circuits with discrete 1% R ratio (-40dB or worse CMRR) for differential amplifiers are good but no match for INAs which use laser-matched Rs to achieve CMRR of 120 dB and even this is GBW dependent.

Remember this:

1. RF coupling on ground tracks is mostly inductive not pure resistive
2. "Ground = 0 V" for each circuit
3. it may be used for a reference, regardless if A or D or protective earth(PE) or floating with CM coupled DC-DC switching noise transients conducted via 1 to 4.7nF caps to PE gnd.
4. Rf coupling between high dI/dt logic currents and dielectric FR4 or air is capacitive for high impedance nodes or may be magnetically induced from mutual coupling loops of mutual area and gap.
5. The impedance of a square conductor end-to-end is constant nH, whether it is 10 x 10 nm or 10 x 10 cm.

The secret is to model your understanding of parasitic reactance and radiative+conductive noise in your schematic simulation to match your measurements then learn from the corrections in Rev B.

For example

This is how a recent question appeared on the 300 MHz DSO using my simuation.

[image]

But this is somewhat like what the OP used for  schematic with textbook waveforms.

[image]

The lesson to be learnt is to model the ground plane impedances with conductance and crosstalk then add to the "logic diagram" simulate it until you recognize the fault in your layout. Then you will understand the rules for combining logic schematics and EMI into something as good as a 3D software package worth >$100k per seat.

Anecdotal

That's how I achieved 60 dB SNR using 20 PCB's on a backplane for an Eddy  design PLL design surrounded by tons of SCADA telemetry & logic & RF in order to measure 10 ppm polar impedance displayed on a Tek XY CRT for testing on nuclear reactor secondary heat-exchanger tubing previously exposed to 10k atmospheres of heavy water drained for maintenance tests. (Circa '77 before Falstad using mental simulation of Henry Ott's experience).